# nokogiri parsing first td in tr ignoring specific class

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have the following html

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>value</th>
      <th>description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>OverallHealthScore</td>
      <td>

             Overall HealthScore.

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="deprecated">DESTAGED_TRACKS_PER_SEC</td>
      <td>

             The tracks per second saved into disks.

      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are many many tr's but this is an excerpt of the two scenario's
I need to only print out OverallHealthScore

```
table.css('tr').map do |row|
    puts row.css('td:not(.deprecated)').map(&:text)[0]
end
```

Gets me just about there but prints out the "description" td on the deprecated items. I can't seem to figure out what I need to do in order to get the results I am needing.

Comment: hey, your question is very unclear. 'what I need to do in order to get the results I am needing' barely explains anything. you will atleast need to share the example html snippets and the outputs you are expecting.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for commenting. I need to extract only OverallHealthScore not DESTAGED_TRACKS_PER_SEC. Assume there are more rows with no class=deprecated specification and assume there are more with the class=deprectated I would like to end with an array of non deprecated metrics

Comment: just `puts table.css('td:first-child:not(.deprecated)').map(&:text)` should do then.

Comment: `td:eq(1):not(.deprecated)` and `td[1]:not(.deprecated)` also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the first td's value which are not deprecated:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OverallHealthScore</td>
    <td>

      Overall HealthScore.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="deprecated">DESTAGED_TRACKS_PER_SEC</td>
    <td>

      The tracks per second saved into disks.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AvaiableAnother</td>
    <td>

      Another Available HealthScore.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="deprecated">OTHER_DEPRE</td>
    <td>

      The tracks per second saved into disks.

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then

```
puts table.css('td:first-child:not(.deprecated)').map(&:text)
# OverallHealthScore
# AvaiableAnother
```